# what's the point of std::unique_ptr::get

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, unique-ptr

Doesn't `std::unique_ptr::get` defeat the purpose of having a unique_ptr in the first place?
I would have expected this function to change its state so it holds no more pointer.
Is there an actual useful use of std::unique_ptr::get?

Comment: what if you want to pass a pointer to the object to a library, such as any OS call?

Comment: Here's a [use case for get](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4679/shared-ptr-and-file-for-wrapping-cstdio-update-also-dlfcn-h).

Comment: You can do `std::addressof(*p)` anyway. There's no need to pretend that the underlying pointer isn't here.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

`std::unique_ptr` provides unique ownership semantics safely. However that doesn't rule out the need for *non-owning* pointers. `std::shared_ptr` has a non-owning counterpart, `std::weak_ptr`. Raw pointers operate as `std::unique_ptr`'s non-owning counterpart.

Comment: I think this one should actually be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 89):

You use it every time you need to pass raw pointer to, say, a C function:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer( new char[1024] );
// ... fill the buffer
int rc = ::write( fd, buffer.get(), len );
```

Comment: You could also use `&buffer[0]`, and then it still works if some uncouth hacker changes it back to a raw pointer.

Answer (score 40):

The rule I tend to follow is this:  if the callee isn't mucking with lifetime/ownership, do not pass it a smart pointer; rather, pass in a raw C++ reference (preferred) or raw pointer.  I find it far cleaner and more flexible to separate the concern of ownership from usage.

Answer (score 24):

When your hands are tied and you do need to pass a pointer to something, `p.get()` reads better than `&*p`.

There is a function that changes the state so the `unique_ptr` doesn't hold a pointer anymore, and that one is named `release`. This is mostly useful to transfer ownership to other smart pointers that don't provide direct construction from a `unique_ptr`. Any other use risks leaking the resource.

Comment: Is there theoretically any performance difference? I've always done &*

Comment: @Carbon: `&*` is probably theoretically faster since it doesn't have the predictability guarantee of `.get()` but subsequently it is practically more dangerous since [it can lead to undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33441609/whats-with-unique-ptrget-instead-of).

Answer (score -2):

There is the obvious situation when you need to call a C API, or a poorly designed C++ API.

Comment: Why would a C++ API be "poorly designed" if it forces you to use a *specific* smart pointer implementation? Even moreso if the API itself does not claim ownership of the pointer?

Comment: For 'poorly designed' read also 'old, from the time before smart pointers were in the standard library/people used Boost'.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I typically pass const-references or references to functions, if that reference dies at the end of the call. This makes the calling-code slightly clumsier, like `foo(*something)`, but I think it is a better design than using pointers there because it better protects against function-contract-bugs while not putting constraints on a pointer-type.

Answer (score -5):

Herb Sutter has a good explanation (around 3:40)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE

The main advantage is that the unique pointer keeps track of how many other references there are to that pointer. You only work with the unique pointer when you are working with ownership. When you want to do something with the data with that pointer, you pass the raw pointer.

Comment: "The main advantage is that the unique pointer keeps track of how many other references there are to that pointer" This is true for shared_ptr, not unique_ptr.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` does not keep track, how many references there are to a pointer. They are unique, so there is exactly one reference. If you need reference counting, `std::shared_ptr` is the way to go.