# What's with unique_ptr::get() instead of &*?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm using `unique_ptr` to manage some resources for safe destruction in every circumstance, etc.

```
void do_something(BLOB* b);
unique_ptr<BLOB> b(new_BLOB(20));
```

Is `&*` much worse than get? e.g.

```
do_something(&*b);
```

or

```
do_someting(b.get());
```

both seem to work.

Comment: That's pretty much comparable to using `&*` with an iterator.

Comment: "worse" is subjective term, in what sense it is worse?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`&*b` is not necessarily equivalent to `b.get()`. In order to be sure to recieve a pointer to the managed object, you want to use `get()`.
There are two reasons:

- Calling `operator*` on a `unique_ptr` not managing any object is undefined behaviour
- The managed object of type `T` may overload `operator&` and as such you may not recieve a valid pointer to `T`.

The standard defines the bevaiour of `operator*` of `std::unique_ptr`:

> `typename add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const;`
>
> 1. Requires: `get() != nullptr`
> 2. Returns: `*get()`

Thus, applying `operator*` (from `&*`) is not allowed if `get()` returns `nullptr`.

You will get the return value of any overloaded `operator&` in the managed object if present. This can be circumvented by using `std::addressof` but the undefined behaviour problem persists.

`std::unique_ptr<T>::get()` will give you the address of the managed object or `nullptr` if no object is managed. It is safer to use `get()` and you have a predictable result.

Answer (score 17):

The [`operator*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) has undefined behavior if no memory is owned by the `unique_ptr` where as [`get()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) will return `nullptr`.

If the `unique_ptr` could ever be empty I would suggest using `get()` otherwise there is no difference.

Answer (score 3):

As has been pointed out by other answers, if the `unique_ptr` does not manage any object, use of `&*` leads to undefined behavior.

For cases where `unique_ptr` manages a pointer, in most cases,

```
do_something(&*b);
```

is equivalent to

```
do_someting(b.get());
```

The only time you could get different results is if `BLOB` has an `operator&` overload that returns a pointer that is different than the address of the object.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an opinion based question.

I happen to think `&*ptr` looks ugly and it isn't clear to a reader why it is written like that. But it does have the advantage that it works with smart pointers and regular pointers.

Comment: That advantage can also be achieved by template specialisation or type traits.

Comment: Although you think it is an opinion based question, you gave a good technical reason for &*