# Initializing a variable to an object from a vector holding derived classes

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr

I have a vector that holds Objects that are derived classes from a Base class "SceneObject". For this task, I found that I had to use unique pointers, as seen here:

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<SceneObject>> objects;
```

To put my objects inside this vector, I allocate memory on the heap with the *new* keyword:

```
objects.emplace_back(new Sphere(glm::vec3(0.9, -1.925, -6.69), 0.825, sphereMaterial));
```

I access functions from these objects in a loop like:

```
objects[k]->intersect(...);
```

But my problem is that I want to initialize a variable "SceneObject" that will contain one of the objects stored in this vector to perform some checks later... I'm trying to store the pointer instead, as I think I should be doing, but I'm getting a compiler error when doing this:

```
SceneObject* object = NULL;
for(...)
    object = &objects[k];
```

The error:

```
boilerplate.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
boilerplate.cpp:606:15: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<SceneObject> > >::value_type* {aka std::unique_ptr<SceneObject>*}' to 'SceneObject*' in assignment
    object = &objects[k];
           ^
```

I used this method as seen in [this example code](http://ideone.com/Z5bQk) for creating my base/derived classes.

Any suggestion as to how I should initialize this variable with my object?

Comment: Why not use a `std::shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `get` on `std::unique_ptr` [to "unwrap" the raw pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10802046/335858) stored inside:

```
SceneObject* object = NULL;
for(...)
    object = objects[k].get();
```

Note that you can avoid unwrapping the pointer in situations when you own the API: `std::unique_ptr` provides dereference operators, allowing you to treat them as if they were actual pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Remember what a `unique_ptr` actually is: it is an object which manages your pointer and only allows one instance to point to a given object.

So an element of your vector is a `unique_ptr` which means that when you do `objects[k]` you are getting a `unique_ptr` object back.  You are trying to initialize a `SceneObject*` pointer to a `unique_ptr*` here:

`SceneObject* object = NULL;
 object = &objects[k];`

But obviously `SceneObject*` != `unique_ptr*`

The goal of smart pointers is to avoid using raw pointers, so if you're using `unique_ptr`'s in the vector, and are fine with the vector element being destructed, you should use `unique_ptr<SceneObject> object;` with your loop too.  Then it's just:

`for(...)
    object = objects[k];`

If you want them to remain valid in the vector, you should be using `shared_ptr`'s in both locations.